# Checking if argumentSyntax is valid to be invoked with a method that has IParameterSymbol

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have 2 methods:

```
public void Method1(object[] args); // In Class A
public void Method2(string a, SomeClass b); // In Class B
```

And 2 Classes:

```
public class SomeClass {}
public class FromSomeClass : SomeClass {}
```

And a code that I analyze using Roslyn:

```
var c = new FromSomeClass();
Method1("a", c);
```

I want to analyze Method1 Call and check if it also a valid Method2 Call, meaning:

```
Method2("a", c); // will this run ok?
```

I got to the point where I got Method2 from the semantic model (IParameterSymbol)
and for each argument in the invocation I have the I have the ITypeSymbol.
How do I check if the argument type is valid for this IParameterSymbol? (both inheritance and implicit conversion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `CSharpCompilation.ClassifyConversion` or `VisualBasicCompilation.ClassifyConversion` to figure out if a conversion exists. Note that the methods are language-specific since each language has some unique rules for conversions.